# How prevent duplicated list object in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a duplicating problem on my component which i get some dummy data from api.

Which following approach everything works well but when i change route and go to another page and back to page where i list my users object. Every time there is a duplicated list of my object. How i can prevent it?

**here is my component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux' 
import {getAllUsers} from '../actions/user'

class users extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAllUsers()
  }

  render() {
    let usersList = this.props.users.map(user => <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>)

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>user list</h1>
        <ul>
          {usersList}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  users: state.users
})


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getAllUsers: bindActionCreators(getAllUsers, dispatch)
  }
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(users)
```

**here is my reducer:**

```
import { FETCH_USERS } from '../actions/user'

let initialState = []

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_USERS:
            return [...state, ...action.payload]
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**and here is my action:**

```
export const FETCH_USERS = 'FETCH_USERS';

export const getAllUsers = () => {
    return(dispatch) => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(users => {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_USERS,
                payload: users
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Because each time your component mount it call the fetch user method and instead of replacing your state with the new data, you're pushing the new data to the current state. Replace `[...state,...action.payload]` by `[...action.payload]`

Comment: @Alexis understood. I fixed it and everything work well. Thank you so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few options available to you at the moment:

1. Evaluate whether you need to carry out the API request. If you've already made the request, can you just rely upon previously cached data in your Redux store, or do you have to rely on new users being fetched every time the component mounts?

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.users.length) {
        this.props.getAllUsers();
    }
}
```

2. If you need to fetch new data every time the component mounts, why not just clear the data in the Redux store when the component unmounts? E.g.

**Component:**

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.clearUsers();
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
import { FETCH_USERS, CLEAR_USERS } from '../actions/user'

let initialState = []

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_USERS:
            return [...state, ...action.payload]
        case CLEAR_USERS:
            return initialState
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

There are a few others options to investigate, but that should hopefully solve your issue :)

**Edit:**

As pointed out in comments, the author's reducer is a little all over the place. I'd look to refactor the reducer to something along the lines of:

```
import { FETCH_USERS } from '../actions/user'

const initialState = {
    users: [],
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_USERS:
            return {
                ...state,
                users: [...action.payload],
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

This would solve the issue of the users being duplicated each time the component mounts, whilst ensuring the reducer can be expanded upon in the future without risking the entirety of the state being replaced.

Comment: Its approach too nicely. Thank you

Comment: @user3348410 Good approach but anyway avoid to do [...state,...action.payload] because you're getting the same data.

Comment: @Alexis good point, however, that might trip you up as you start to expand your actions as you're going to overwrite the entirety of the state.

Comment: @tombraider the payload is containing the users array, if you're not doing this it will not detect an update of the state and doesn't trigger the refresh of the component if the data have changed. And with your first approach it will never refresh the data even if they are updated. And with your second approach you're doing 2 actions instead of only refreshing the users. Useless to clear them if you just need to load them each time.

Comment: The author's reducer needs a fair bit of work, and I would be using an object rather than an array for the initial state, but I stand by my point that if you do not spread your state, it's going to cause issues if you ever expand that reducer. I'll update my answer.

Comment: One more time, it's not a good practical to use specific propery inside the state, your approach is working for this specific example but not viable for a durable application with an evoluting state. https://redux.js.org/glossary#reducer take a look on this, a reducer is done to reduce a collection.

Comment: Please point out what specific property we're setting in the edited reducer above? The approach of spreading state is commonly used in Redux reducers. If we didn't spread the state and the author expanded this reducer to handle other actions, it would cause all manner of issues.

Comment: @tombraider thank you. I used edited reducer approach but getting error TypeError: this.props.users.map is not a function

Comment: That updated reducer is going to change how your data is mapping to your props. Take a look at your state in Redux and compare that to your `mapStateToProps` function. You'll probably find the users array is now located at `state.users.users`. As the naming for that is a little weird, you might want to change the name of your reducer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you're calling `fetchUser` method of your Reducer each time your component is `mounting`. 
When your `router` change the route the components are `unmount` and remount after go back the `fetchUser` is call again.

Inside your `FETCH_USERS` action instead of replacing the old data by the new one you are pushing the new data to the current state.

Your issue will be solved by replacing `[...state,...action.payload]` by `[...action.payload]`

Answer (score 1):

Alexis suggestion works fine as long as you only have users in your state. As soon as you will add more properties, this won't work anymore as it clears the whole state.

Try something like this in your FETCH_USERS case:

let newState = {...state};

newState.users = [];

newState.users.push(action.payload);

return newState;

Comment: That's why you have to create a specific store and combine the reducers by type of data, it's better than manage a lot of different properties in your state.

Comment: His reducer may grow with more properties. Clearing the whole state, for this reducer, will break if more properties are to be added for this reducer.

Comment: Thanks for marking my answer as not useful, Alexis.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each time the FETCH_USERS case in your reducer is hit, it appends additional data (action.payload) on top of your existing data (state). Since this happens each time your component mounts, it appends old data to the array frequently. Here is the situation explained in more detail:

if  your payload equals the array [ "id1", "id2" ], then the first time the component mounts this will be put into the state which will make

```
state = ["id1", "id2"]
```

The next time the component mounts, the user array is still equal to [ "id1", "id2" ] maybe with the addition of new users or some no longer there. Let's say "id3" is also added. The reducer takes this and appends it to the previous state:

```
state = ["id1", "id2"]
action.payload = ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
```

so...

```
return [...state, ...action.payload] = [ "id1", "id2", "id1", "id2", "id3" ]
```

Repeats are added.

To fix this you need to just fill the state with the payload, and not persist the previous state since the list of users is being retrieved again without filtering out previously existing users

```
return [...action.payload]
```

Your reducer should now look like this:

```
import { FETCH_USERS } from '../actions/user'

let initialState = []

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_USERS:
            return [...action.payload]
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```